# Excel VBA needed so what do I Google to find my answer?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm pretty much a master of solving my own problems in Excel, largely in thanks to people like you all. Our company is migrating to new vacation rental software and I've run into something I've never experienced before. I don't know how to google this issue to find my own answer. Most of the searches I've used lead to Microsoft Excel info for newb type issues. So I've been stuck manually doing this every time I sync rates while in the software transition.

~~~~~~~~~~~~

Fun Side Note: I use AutoHotkey to edit the new software and have made 18,000 edits at a rate of 4/second and blown some minds...

~~~~~~~~~~

Basically, I don't know how to ask the question efficiently enough for google to even give me a hint. I can't even explain it to you humans without pics.

I can't use "transpose" because that is just "high school" enough for people to write blogs about how to transpose data. I know how to transpose. Plus, I've already transposed this data to get it to this format.

I need to loop/while through an export's top row, which contains data, not header text and then grab the rental rates under it and move it to one giant list.

How do I google this?

Orig Data:

[image: Original Data]

Desired Results:

[image: Result Goal]

Comment: I was attempting to show images to make it easier on you guys, but my points are too low. Confusion policy because is discourages help due to the added work to understand the question. This is probably a Rumsfeldian situations where I don't know enough to know I don't know.

Comment: I've fixed the images. It looks similar to de-pivoting, but searching for that will probably lead you up the garden path, with only a small chance of finding something useful. I would call it a data transformation, but searching for that would be worse. Anyways, this could be done with either VBA *or* formulas.

Comment: Yup, that's un-pivoting. PowerQuery / "Get & Transform" can do that, do you have it installed? Excel 2016? [PowerQuery unpivot](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098) yields interesting results I find.

Comment: I've never even heard of those two terms. I was just in the middle of recording macros and then trying to bend that code into a loop through top row. 

Off to google! I'll report back.

Comment: Yes. Excel 2016. Full Office from O365 Enterprise 1 and Business Premium licenses. Access but missing some of the big data stuff.

Comment: Well that was a link right there, to an MSDN article about how to go about using PowerQuery to unpivot data..

Comment: The power query is going to allow me to stop using MS Access for another routine process I frequent so thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to go the Pivot Table/Power Query route (and I'm not even sure it's possible to do it that way, as this is not a straightforward un-pivot), the following is a formula only solution.

Assuming your original data is in worksheet `Sheet1`, set up a second worksheet like this:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `A2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down into the column as far as required:

```dart
=INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1,INT((ROW()-2)/(COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1))+3)
```

Enter the following formula in `B2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-right&down into columns `B:C` as far as required:

```dart
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$B,MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1)+2,COLUMN()-1)
```

Enter the following formula in `D2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down into the column as far as required:

```dart
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$H,MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1)+2,INT((ROW()-2)/(COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1))+3)
```

Comment: I FELT I got close using formulas last week but my longest was about about half the length of your shortest so I guess I was not so close after all. 

Thanks!

Comment: I can't believe I just got exactly what I wanted in 7 minutes and 3 formulas.

Comment: @charlyRoot You're welcome.